# Is there a variable or an option to add custom build.prop options while compiling AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I've been looking for this quest all over but couldn't find one. So decided to ask it myself.

So I'm compiling an AOSP ROM for my phone. And I'm willing to add 2 additional parameters to build.prop which will be generated.

Currently I'm doing it manually. Is there an option to do it automatically.

Like the is this variable called "PRODUCT_BUILD_PROP_OVERRIDES" and it has the option to override build description and fingerprint.

And my question is, will I be able to add the below two lines in a similar way.

persist.camera.eis.enable=1
persist.camera.HAL3.enabled=1

Kindly let me know if you guys have any idea on how to do it...!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can add a line at bottom of the file device/{vendor}/{device-name}/device.mk and write PRODUCT_BUILD_PROP_OVERRIDES in it. and write these two property values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you device.mk:

```
PRODUCT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES += \
    persist.camera.eis.enable=1 \
    persist.camera.HAL3.enabled=1
```